# Java using iText to set a table border

Tags: java, html, itext

I am building a pdf from html and I want to set the table border.
here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Digital </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:Arial">

    <table style="width:100%" border=\"2\">
        <tr>
            <th>depo date</th>
            <th>MMR</th>
            <th>SUM</th>
            <th>NUM</th>
            <th>ACCOUNT</th>
            <th>TNUM</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td dir="rtl">$data.depo</td>
            <td dir="rtl">$data.MR</td>
            <td dir="rtl">$data.Sum</td>
            <td dir="rtl">$data.Num</td>
            <td dir="rtl">$data.accoun</td>
            <td dir="rtl">$data.branch</td> 
            <td dir="rtl">$data.TNum</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Following [iText-add-table-to-pdf](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker-itext5/html-tables), the only diffrence is adding  `border=\"2\"` to the table, but it still does not work, is there more changes I need to add?

The create pdf function(same is the one on the tutorial):

```
public void createPdf(String file, String htmlString, String pathToTTF) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        // step 1
        Document document = new Document();
        // step 2
        PdfWriter writer =
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
        // step 3
        document.open();
        // step 4
        // Styles
        CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
        XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider =
            new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS); //
        fontProvider.register(pathToTTF);
        CssAppliers cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(fontProvider);
        HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers);
        htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

        // Pipelines
        PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
        HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
        CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

        // XML Worker
        XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
        XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
        p.parse(new FileInputStream(htmlString), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        // step 5
        document.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using pdfHtml when converting html to pdf.
pdfHtml is the latest tool in our addon-section that does this task, and has a far greater range when it comes to both CSS and HTML constructions.

Comment: That may or may not solve the problem though. The answer would probably be something like: use CSS. I have some pdfHTML examples. For instance, the HTML created [here](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/zugferd-future-invoicing/6-creating-html-invoices) can be converted into PDF shown [here](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/zugferd-future-invoicing/7-creating-pdf-invoices-comfort).

Comment: Yes it does the trick, I just applied some inline or external CSS, thanks!